# Find closest field list in pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have the next field in my db:

```
{
   "result": [1,0,0,1,0]
}
```

First I need to find direct entry and it's easy.
But if I don't find the same list, I need to find the closest match.
Example: [1,1,0,1,0] is closest to "result" than [1,1,1,1,0].
How can I do it with Pymongo?

Edit: find the solution. Just change the query to find until I find a similar one.

Comment: are all of your results binary? what's your definition of "closest"? we need more context if we're going to be able to help

Comment: Please give an example dataset and expected output. What you have supplied is not informative enough. It is causing us to make guesses or  assumptions and more questions for you and us both. [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) isn't just a cool acronym.

Comment: @wpercy @Jaba I have an field in my database like this: ```{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c5f7896aa49be2fcf381b47"), "user_id" : 466172382, "result" : [ 
        1,0,1,0,1
    ]```. It`s answers for a quiz. And now I need to find field with same result or closest match like [1,1,1,0,1].

Comment: but again, if your result is `[0,1,0,1,0]`, which is "closer" `[1,1,0,1,0]` or `[0,1,1,1,0]`? You need to give more context.